# Fluids for Citreon Berlingo Diesel With Manual Transmission

Tags: diesel, manual-transmission, citroen, clutch-hydraulics

Opened the bonnet, looked to LHS beyond screen-wash reservoir, removed cap on (?) hydraulic oil, found it to be RED in colour and below minimum level when engine not running.

Went to shop: insisted I buy hydraulic oil for *manual* - GREENish in colour! 
Panicked. Went to another shop: bought hydraulic oil for *automatic* - RED in colour.

Confused!

1. Can I mix manual and automatic hydraulic oil?
2. Low/dry reservoir - does it greatly damage clutch?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to top off the master cylinder on your clutch reservoir? What year is your Citroen Berlingo? Engine (which diesel)? Miles?

Comment: I am asking about the small reservoir immediately behind the screen wash reservoir. This is not the main engine oil reservoir (tested by the dip-stick). The reservoir in question is tested by looking to see if the level is above minimum. My diesel Citreon is 1.9. Year 2001. Can I mix red and green "hydraulic" oil? Why am I pressurised to use "automatic" oil for my manual gear change?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you opened the power steering reservoir.  If so, these usually use the same red dexron fluid as automatic transmissions.

Usually there is a symbol on the cap to identify it.  Quite often the power steering has a steering wheel symbol.  You really need to know exactly what to put in before you add anything.

Comment: cap - hmm, my friend lost the capwhen he was topping up at a service station. I'veput a temporary cap on until I can get a proper replacement.

Comment: does this resrvoir have a filter with the (missing) cap?

Comment: is the clutch damage - I had to replace clutch because couldn't change gears - related to the low level in this reservoir (or is it a coincidence)?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the owners manual (if you don't have it, check online there may be a PDF version available). That should both tell you what the various reservoirs are for and what is supposed to go in them.